# Apexcharts update series

Tags: apexcharts

I want to change my widget but I only want to change

```
    series: [<?php echo $data['campaign']['0']->report_summary->open_rate * 100?>],
```

To the new data I am getting something like series: [100], But this is not working

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
                    var element = document.getElementById("kt_mixed_widget_18_chart");

                    var height = parseInt(KTUtil.css(element, 'height'));

                    if (!element) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var options = {
                        series: [<?php echo $data['campaign']['0']->report_summary->open_rate * 100?>],
```

```
 chart.updateOptions([{
        series: [newData]
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked!

```
ApexCharts.exec('chart_id', 'updateSeries', [5]);
```